# Custom data type to JSON

Tags: c#, json, custom-data-type

I have custom data type classes which I want .NET to convert to JSON (and later also back to CustomDataType).

I know that classes without any special definition will be converted to objects, simply by serializing all public properties. But this is not what I need.

Let's assume that I have a class

```
public class MyString : System.Object {
    private string myString;
    public MyString(string str) {
        this.myString = str;
    }
    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    public override int GetHashCode()
    public string ToString() {
        return "!!!"+myString+"!!!";
    }
}
```

Now, if I use this type in my ApiController

```
public class MyItem {
    public MyString someStr;
}
public class MyApiController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    public MyItem MyApi() {
        MyItem item = new MyItem();
        item.someStr = new MyString("I have a dream");
        return item;
    }
}
```

I get

```
{"someStr":{}}
```

but I may want to get

```
{"someStr":"!!!I have a dream!!!"}
```

or

```
{"someStr":{"words":4,"chars":11,"length":14}}
```

without actually exposing any properties as public.

How would I achieve that?

Comment: Why are you explictly deriving from `Object`??????

Comment: I can't imagine a single case where it makes any sense at all to serialize private properties, it kind of defeats the whole concept of private. And then, how would you imagine to deserialize them?

Comment: But somehow, String, Int32, Boolean, and if you don't like these "primitive" data types, DateTime, are serialized differently than "object containing all public properties". I hope that Microsoft didn't choose to handle only these types different from others in their JSON Serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebApi is using a Json serializer to get your result, when you're expecting it to execute a `ToString()` on it.

I personally haven't dealt with a lot of private variables (or properties) when serializing objects, however, it doesn't surprise me that it's doing this.

In order to get the desired result, you'll need to expose a property that returns `!!!<whatever text>!!!`.